# Simplification of Terms $ 2^{(1/\ln2)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The final answer is $\mathrm e$. Can anyone show steps? 
$ 2^{(1/\ln2)}$

I tried log laws without any result. I'm pretty sure I'm stuck somewhere really easy.

Comment: $e^{\ln(2^{(1/ln2)})}=e^{((1/\ln2)\cdot\ln2)}=e^1=e$

Where in the first step we used the property $\ln{(a^b)}=b\ln{a}$

Comment: $2 = e^{\log(2)}$

Comment: Boy was that easy. How do I vote you up?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are referring to me or to Brad's comment... either way you can vote up a comment by clicking on the arrow/triangle which appears if you move your cursor on top of the comment itself but it won^t affect reputation points. So $\ddot\smile$ and enjoy your day

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{\frac{1}{\ln2}}=x$$
$$\ln\left(2^{\frac{1}{\ln2}}\right)=\ln x$$
$$\frac{1}{\ln2}\cdot\ln2=\ln x$$
$$1=\ln x$$
$$x=e^1=e$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to deal with this, using the "change-of-base" formula:

From

$$ \log_b \ x \ = \ \frac{\log_a \ x}{\log_a \ b} \ \ , $$

we have

$$ \ln \ 2 \ = \ \log_e \ 2 \ = \ \frac{\log_2 \ 2}{\log_2 \ e} \ = \ \frac{1}{\log_2 \ e} \ \ . $$

Thus,

$$ 2^{1 / \ln 2} \ = \ 2^{\log_2 \ e \ } \ = \ e \ \ . $$

[We can see that there is a general relation $  \log_b \ a \ = \ \frac{1}{\log_a \ b} \ \ . $ ]

Answer (score 1):

Try this: $1/ln2  =  lne/ln2$ which using the base conversion formula is $log_2e$ thus you get $2^{log_2e}$ which is exactly the same as simply $e$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The general  *definition* of $a^b$ is via the exponential function: $a^b:=\exp(b\ln a)$.